# Cost effectiveness of Amazon SimpleDB/RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'm looking at both of these services because I don't want to bother to maintain backups of my databases. My question is: how cost effective are these services? Specifically, how are they billed? I see that they're billed by hour, but what does this mean? Does it mean if I make 1 query in an hour I am billed for the full hour, or rather just for the amount of time the query took to execute?

Answer (score 4):

As you probably know, Amazon SimpleDB is not a relation database, but a “NoSQL” service.  It is billed by storage space used and data transfer in and out.

Amazon RDS are traditional MySQL servers, and you are billed for the number of hours that the server is running, as well as storage, I/O and data transfer.

Since you are looking at both of these, I’m guessing you havnt decided yet whether to use a NoSQL solution or a relational database. I am going to assume that you might be more interested in RDS since it is traditional MySQL, and I noticed you had another question about MySQL here on SO.

So the advantages of using RDS is letting them to the setup/maintenance for you, such as:

- Managed - Amazon RDS handles time-consuming database management tasks, such as patch management, backups, and replication
- Automated backups - This allows you
  to restore your DB Instance to any
  second during your retention period,
  up to the last five minutes. Your
  automatic backup retention period can
  be configured to up to eight days.
- Scalable – extremely easy to
  upgrade/downgrade your DB instance if
  needed
- Multi-AZ/Read Replicas – 2
  replication options available of
  needed

You can sort of determine the cost-effectiveness by looking at the hourly rates. Let’s say you wanted 1 Small DB Instance (A small instance is 1.7 GB memory, 1 ECU (1 virtual core with 1 ECU), 64-bit platform, Moderate I/O Capacity).

A small instance is $0.11 per hour, so if you ran that for 1 year it would be $963.60
However, they also offer reserved instances, in which you pay an upfront charge but then your hourly rate is reduced.

If you purchased a 1 year reserved small instance, it would be $227.50 upfront cost, plus $0.046 per hour, so it would be $630.46 for a year.

They also have a 3 year reserved instance, which are $350 upfront and $0.046 per hour. If you ran this for 3 years it would be $752.96 for the first year and $402.96 for the second and third years.

Info from: http://aws.amazon.com/rds/

Comment: Are you sure they charge by 'running' hour? Couldn't it be they charge by CPU time?

Comment: Bart, good question: AWS is always billed by running hour (for all EC2-based services like RDS) and not CPU time. Also it is billed on full hour increments. So if you run an instance for 1hr and 10mins, you are billed for 2hrs.

Comment: Just to clarify my answer, ec2 is billed by running hour and simpledb is billed by CPU time each query takes. Sorry Bart, I probably misunderstood your comment to be pertaining to Joe's comments about ec2 near the end and not simpledb in general.